# Flickity & Swup - destroying flickity

Tags: javascript, flickity, swup

I am trying to destroy and re-load my Flickity slideshow while using Swup for page transitions, and I am not having much luck. This is my js file:

```
import Swup from 'swup';

var Flickity = require('flickity');

function init() {
  if (document.querySelector('.testimonials-slideshow')) {
    var flkty = new Flickity('.testimonials-slideshow', {
      wrapAround: true,
      pageDots: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      arrowShape: 'M68.374,83.866L31.902,50L68.374,16.134L64.814,12.3L24.214,50L64.814,87.7L68.374,83.866Z'
    });
  }
}

function unload() {
  flkty.destroy();
}

init();

const swup = new Swup();

swup.on('contentReplaced', init);

swup.on('willReplaceContent', unload);
```

But when I try this I get the error `flkty is not defined`. Can anyone give me any pointers on this?

Comment: The `var` keyword makes `flkty` a _local_ variable in the scope of your `init` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variable scoping

As mentioned by CBroe, your `var` is undefined because of where you define it. It is defined in a function, but should be defined at the "top level".

```
import Swup from 'swup';

var Flickity = require('flickity');

// Added a "global" definition here:
var flkty;

function init() {
  if (document.querySelector('.testimonials-slideshow')) {
    // Removed var:
    flkty = new Flickity('.testimonials-slideshow', {
      wrapAround: true,
      pageDots: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      arrowShape: 'M68.374,83.866L31.902,50L68.374,16.134L64.814,12.3L24.214,50L64.814,87.7L68.374,83.866Z'
    });
  }
}

function unload() {
  flkty.destroy();
}

init();

const swup = new Swup();

swup.on('contentReplaced', init);

swup.on('willReplaceContent', unload);
```

Furthermore, if you are using any kind of module bundler, sometimes it can still get lost, so you could consider doing something like:

```
window.flkty = new Flickity('.testimonials-slideshow', ...
```

And always reference it in that way, i.e.

```
window.flkty.destroy();
```

### Only destroying instances that exist

That's it for your variable definition. The next potential error is that you only init `flkty` when the query selector matches:

```
if (document.querySelector('.testimonials-slideshow')) {
```

But you destroy it every `willReplaceContent`, so really you could do with a check on "is it inited, this page load?". In this instance, you can do a check like so:

```
// Init the var as false:
var flkty = false

function init() {
  if (document.querySelector('.testimonials-slideshow')) {
    flkty = new Flickity('.testimonials-slideshow', ...);
  }
}

function unload() {
  if(flkty){
    flkty.destroy();
    // Make sure the flkty var is set to false at the end:
    flkty = false;
  }
}
```

### Neatening up your code

This can all get a bit out of hand, so what we started doing was creating modules. Here is a skeleton of a carousel module we use:

```
// modules/Carousel.js
import Swiper from "swiper";

export default {
  carouselEl: null,
  carouselSwiper: null,
  setup() {
    this.carouselEl = document.getElementById("header-carousel");
    if (!this.carouselEl) {
      // Just stop if there is no carousel on this page
      return;
    }
    this.carouselSwiper = new Swiper(this.carouselEl, { ... });
    this.carouselSwiper.on("slideChange", () => { ... });
  },
  destroy() {
    // If we already have one:
    if (this.carouselSwiper) {
      this.carouselSwiper.destroy();
    }
    // Make sure we are reset, ready for next time:
    this.carouselSwiper = null;
  },
};
```

Then, in our main.js we do something like you have:

```
import Carousel from "./modules/Carousel.js";

function init(){
  Carousel.setup();
  // Add more here as the project grows...
}
function unload(){
  Carousel.unload();
}

swup = new Swup();
swup.on("contentReplaced", init);
swup.on("willReplaceContent", unload);
init();
```

All of the modules have `setup` and `unload` functions that won't break if the elements don't exist, so we can call all of them on each page load and unload.

I love swup but also have personal experience in the nightmare of initing and destroying things so let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Hi Mike, perhaps update your question with your new code, or ask a new question and I can see if I can take a look.

Comment: That worked thank you - I had an issue with a conflict with another script which threw me off, but working through your example above all works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Ah that is awesome, I'm so pleased!